# How to write functions in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going to be writing a callable function which will make use of jQuery. But I can't find any reference to ordinary function declaration with jQuery; it's all about element manipulation functions. Can I essentially just declare an ordinary javascript function and then use jQuery in it, or do I need to be doing something special? Is this okay?

```
function useJQ(xml)
{
    var groups = {};
    $('resultGroups', $(xml)).each(function() {
    var count = $('results', this).length;
    var name = $('name',this).text();
    groups[name] = count;
}
```

Comment: Yep, you can use jQuery in any standard Javascript. Keep in mind that jQuery is just a Javascript library itself, it's not magic :)

Comment: use a closure. (function($){ ...code... })(jQuery) anything inside the function that uses $ is binded to jquery.

Comment: Feels like magic...very complex and powerful magic which I need to read up on before casting any spells with.

Comment: And although I think I won't need it, I'd like to understand: what do you mean "bound to jQuery", and why would I want to as opposed to just going it straight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not extend jQuery to do such tasks. You can use plain functions to do what you need to do. just ensure that you don't pollute the global namespace by setting your own namespace.

However, if just want to use the jQuery namespace instead of your own, here's a quick way to add them:

```
$.fn.functionName = function(){
   //do what your function does
   //"this" in here is the jQuery object you preceded the function
   //to allow chaining, you must return a jQuery object
};
```

the effect is like:

```
$(selector).functionName()
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a collection of helper functions. It doesn't affect how you define your functions. So your present code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not about structuring your javascript code, for that you should use Javascript enclosures, objects and prototype. There a many proposed ways of structuring Javascript code.

You could also take a look at defining [jQuery plugins authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) to help you keep you code more organized.